# How can I use jQuery to append something to the value of a form element, as opposed to changing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I know how to do this in basic JS:

```
document.getElementById("someTextarea").value += "stuff";
```

Note the `+` - I'm adding to the value, not completely changing it. How would I do that using jQuery's [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#foo').val($('#foo').val() + 'something');
```

(Of course you can and should cache the element).

Another way (very jQuery style):

```
$('#foo').val(function(){
    return this.value + "something";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#someTextarea').val(function(i, v){ return v + 'stuff'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since an ID selector will return a unique element you can avoid `val` if you want:

$('#foo')[0].value += ' stuff';